# Startup error in WSL since upgrade

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

I recently opened my Ubuntu app, installed with WSL1 and was greeted with a friendly message to upgrade WSL with the command `wsl.exe --update`.  I did so, restarted my computer, but am now greeted with a less friendly message every time I start the Ubuntu app:

```
<3>WSL (2084) ERROR: CreateProcessEntryCommon:570: execvpe /bin/zsh failed 2
<3>WSL (2084) ERROR: CreateProcessEntryCommon:579: Create process not expected to return
```

As far as I can tell, no functionality is impacted (except `emacs` now opens emacs in GUI mode for some reason).

But these messages annoy me.  Any idea why this is happening?

Versions of things:

```
WSL version: 1.0.3.0
Kernel version: 5.15.79.1
WSLg version: 1.0.47
MSRDC version: 1.2.3575
Direct3D version: 1.606.4
DXCore version: 10.0.25131.1002-220531-1700.rs-onecore-base2-hyp
Windows version: 10.0.19045.2486
```

Comment: Possible:  https://superuser.com/questions/1761555/3wsl-12-error-createprocessentrycommon570-execvpe-usr-bin-zsh

Comment: @Terrance I did see that, but the issue is apparently different.  That user had issues with `$SHELL`, removing zsh and trying to replace it with bash.  My shell is, and always has been, zsh: `echo $SHELL` returns `/home/me/.nix-profile/bin/zsh` as it should.

Comment: @Terrance It has not been removed: `which zsh` returns `/home/me/.nix-profile/bin/zsh` as it should, same as `$SHELL` as in my previous comment.

Comment: So, the error doesn't agree with `which zsh` is returning.  Check the shell.

Comment: Okay, then I guess my question should really be, why is it looking for zsh in /bin when it's always been somewhere else?  I use nix and home-manager to install software.  I didn't have any issues before the upgrade.

Comment: In the linked possibility you would run `wsl ~ -e chsh` and you can change the shell to match what the `which zsh` is outputting.

Comment: What's odd to me is that Ubuntu is actually starting up for you with that error.  Usually, that's a fatal error that will prevent Ubuntu from starting in WSL ...

Comment: I'm not familiar enough with Nix to try to reproduce this.  Can you provide information (probably via edit to your question) on how Zsh was configured under Nix?

Comment: Also, what does `wsl -l -v` show?

Comment: Are you by any chance using a `wsl.exe` command somewhere inside a startup file in Ubuntu?  Still trying to figure out why Ubuntu gives you that message but still is able to start, and that's one possibility that I've come up with ...

Comment: @NotTheDr01ds Thanks for your response.  I did end up `apt install zsh`ing  to shut up the errors, even though I never did that with the previous release. The WSL upgrade must've messed with my nix home-manager environment somehow, but it works, so I'm not going to waste more time on it.  Thanks again for the comments though.

Comment: @user4601931 Certainly.  Glad you got it tamed, at least ;-).